# Do not want session restore

Tags: boot, homepage, session-restore

I don't want IE 11 to reload the previously viewed session ever, and even though I change the setting each time I open the browser, the next session or day it does it again. I should only have to make the change once to have it work. Why does this keep happening?

Comment: Perhaps Brink's suggestion at [www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/62575-internet-explorer-reopen-last-browsing-session-disable-enable](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/62575-internet-explorer-reopen-last-browsing-session-disable-enable.html) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "Delete Browsing History on exit" option. This will ensure, the previously loaded sessions are removed permanently. Try this option and check your outcome.

IE Settings > Internet Options > General tab > check the "Delete Browsing History on exit" option.

[image]